# Firebase authorization in node js

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, authorization

I have simple html,css and js frontend and node.js backend.Im using firebase for authentication at backend.Now how can I protect or authorize some routes.

If any one tries to access a route(say dashboard) without proper authentication then he must redirect to login page or any error message page.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening in your server's firebase instance itself it's being authenticated instead of returning the authentication data to the client. What you should be doing is returning the client authentication token on the request. There's a section covering server authentication here

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/#custom_token_creation

Still issue?

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin